# Compiling 2 Dimensional Constant Arrays Right into Pixel Shader to use as Lookup Table

Tags: fragment-shader

I want to use a small 2 dimensional look up table in a fragment shader, but I don't want to pay for the performance cost of fetching it from memory for every fragment.

Is it feasible/reasonable to simply declare or hardcode the table as an array right inside the fragment shader?  If yes, any indicator as to how big I can make it?

Thanks,
- Jim

Comment: _"I want to use a small 2 dimensional look up table in a fragment shader, but I don't want to pay for the performance cost of fetching it from memory for every fragment."_ Both is using the 'same' memory? If you can calculate it, it would be faster than a lookup (i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly reasonable approach.  When you have a static global table like this, it can be dynamically indexed without going out to memory or consuming general purpose registers.  As a general rule, you should keep the table small enough to fit in a single constant buffer (4096 float4s).  Here's an example:

HLSL:

```
static const float LUT[] =
{
    0, 1, 1, 2,
    3, 5, 8, 13,
    21, 34, 55, 89,
    144, 233, 377, 610,
    987, 1597, 2584, 4181,
    6765, 10946, 17711, 28657
};

float4 main(float a : TEXCOORD) : SV_TARGET
{
    return LUT[a];
}
```

Disassembly:

```
ps_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_immediateConstantBuffer { { 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 1.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 1.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 2.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 3.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 5.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 8.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 13.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 21.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 34.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 55.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 89.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 144.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 233.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 377.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 610.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 987.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 1597.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 2584.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 4181.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 6765.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 10946.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 17711.000000, 0, 0, 0},
                              { 28657.000000, 0, 0, 0} }
dcl_input_ps linear v0.x
dcl_output o0.xyzw
dcl_temps 1
ftou r0.x, v0.x
mov o0.xyzw, icb[r0.x + 0].xxxx
ret
// Approximately 3 instruction slots used
```

Comment: 4096 float 4s!?  Good grief, that's way way larger than I expected possible.  So exactly what specs on the GPU are actually determining that value?  Is it shader instruction slots?

Comment: The spec is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - some hardware may support more. Note that for D3D9 the limit is significantly smaller (256 IIRC).

Comment: A constant buffer works, and is probably a reasonable solution, but it is a form of memory.  On all current GPU architectures as far as I'm aware, the constants are stored in memory and the shader will have to load the values from it, so under normal circumstances I wouldn't expect this to be any faster than loading from a texture.

Comment: It's considerably faster since cbuffer cache scheme is optimized to assume that all threads will hit most of the values in the buffer, unlike the texture cache which assumes most threads will hit only a few of the entries each, but be divergent with a high degree of spatial locality.  As a result, you'll likely get a much higher fraction of cache hits with cbuffers than textures, and for cbuffers in particular, cache hits can be used directly by instructions, and so are basically free.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably fine as long as when you access the table, the index at which you access it is always a compile-time constant, or in a loop where the compiler unrolls it.  For instance, you can do stuff like this:

```
float myTable[10] = { /* hardcoded values here */ };

// Using hardcoded indices
foo = myTable[0] * bar + myTable[5] * baz;

// Using indices in a loop which the compiler can unroll
// (since it has a hardcoded, not-too-large iteration count)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    foo += myTable[i] * farb;
```

This works because when the compiler optimizes the shader, it can optimize away the table, substituting the appropriate hardcoded table value in each place where the table is accessed.  In this case the table can be as large as you like since it will only be used at compile time.

However, this is not likely to go well if you use dynamic indices in your table, or use it from a loop that the compiler can't unroll, since then the table can't be optimized away.  It will have to be stored in registers, and if there are many table entries it will take up a large number of registers - which will impact performance since it reduces the number of shader invocations that can run concurrently.  Also, at the beginning of the shader, you will have to spend a bunch of time populating the table, just executing a lot of move instructions to store the hardcoded values into the registers.  It's not pretty, and it will almost certainly be faster to store the table in memory at that point.

Comment: There shouldn't need to be any mov instructions to populate the table per shader.  Shouldn't it be a fixed cost per draw, so almost no perf hit given a sufficient number of invocations?

Comment: @MooseBoys If you're trying to do this without any form of memory, I believe you have to populate the table per shader.